# Missing dedicated search button on devices

Tags: android, android-intent

My app used to trigger a local search window when ever user tapped on dedicated search button on the device. Lately, all the devices that come out in the market stopped providing that button. 
I know I can provide a search option in the app, but this question is not about that.
Is there a way user can still emulate the triggering of search on the app by some key press combinations?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks,
SKU

Answer (score 0):

Pressing and holding the menu button usually brings up the search function on new android phones (e.g. SGS1 or SGS2)

Comment: Latest phones don't provide a Menu button either.

Comment: i guess you have to build your own combination using `onKeyDown` or `onKeyLongPress`. Also check out this link, here you can find methods to check if a button is pressed: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)